# I want to make dropdown in expandable in all time in flutter,

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[image]

I want to make this dropdown all time expandable state, don't need to un-expandable state. i want to hide or remove un-expandable state in dropdown and i want to show all time expandable to  make true, its possible, is have any idea about it, please add it.
for exapmple, user click the dropdown right icon, don;t need to hide the dropdown items. how to do this

Comment: just made a custom design for yourself using checkbox element and some row

Answer (score 1):

to achieve that design you can made a custom design for it. from what you explain the result should be done like this

[image]

and here is the custom code that I've created

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
final fieldText = TextEditingController();

MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

void clearText() {
    fieldText.clear();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(body: SafeArea(child: ListviewWithCheckBox()))
    );
}
}

class ListviewWithCheckBox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListviewWithCheckBoxState createState() => _ListviewWithCheckBoxState();
}

class _ListviewWithCheckBoxState extends State<ListviewWithCheckBox> {
  List<String> _texts = [
    "T-701 - ZONE 1/2/3",
    "Slide Valves on 1st deck",
    "F-301 - South side",
    "Regen - 13th floor",
  ];

  late List<bool> _isChecked;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isChecked = List<bool>.filled(_texts.length, false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView( 
      child: Column(
        children: [
          CheckboxListTile(
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            title: Text('Oil_and_gas'),
            value: false,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(
                () {
                  // ....
                },
              );
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              itemCount: _texts.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return CheckboxListTile(
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                  title: Text(_texts[index]),
                  value: _isChecked[index],
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        // .....
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

that should work like a charm now